Ubuntu 24.04 CLI to GUI issue
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I ran the the command sudo apt install-gnome-shell-extension-manager and after that, my laptop went to sleep.
Since then, I have been unable to log into my laptop. It shows the login page blurred.
I turned the power off and after that, it permanently switched to CLI mode. I installed LightDM but the GUI failed to show when I started my session.
Please help me to get back in GUI mode.

Run this command sudo apt install gdm3 && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 This will open up  an ncurses command line interface. Select gdm. gdm was the default before you installed lightdm. Then run sudo reboot

The the following commands one by one
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

